# Python which module is best to display rectangles in image?

Tags: python, image, drawing, rectangles, drawrectangle

I am making 2D binpacking tests but I need to display my results through images! It is easy as drawing rectangles (with dims and coordinates) inside bigger rectangles.

I tried pygame, tkinter, matplotlib but I was not really convinced, is there any easier module in order to make that ? I just need to draw several rectangle where I will add severall other rectangle inside..

thank you in advance

Comment: pillow? https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: It could make it, but I guess I can't add graduation ?